# Latex Error: Runaway argument paragraph ended before \@@@cimidrule was complete in table and tabular

Tags: tables, booktabs

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}%[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{Day ahead accuracy assessment}
\label{tab:Day_ahead_Accuracy}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{6}{c} @{}}
    \toprule
 Hours &
 \multicolumn{6}{c}{US utility } \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-7} %\cmidrule(l){10-17}
 &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Without optimization algorithms} &
 \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{With optimization algorithms} &
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{Proposed} \\
 \cmidrule(lr){2} \cmidrule(l){3-6} \cmidrule(l){7} 
    &\theadb{SVR} & \theadb{SVR-PSO} & \theadb{SVR-WO} & \theadb{SVR-CBSSO} & \theadb{SVR-FA} & \theadb{SVR-mFFO}\\ 
\midrule
NSW & 4.81 & 30.1 & 0.325 & 3.35 & 25.3 & 0.500 \\
QLD & 4.84 & 28.4 & 0.625 & 2.80 & 28.9 & 0.590 \\ 

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a single-column `\cmidrule` you need to write, e.g., `\cmidrule{2-2}` rather than `\cmidrule{2}`.

Comment: +1: Unrelated, I just wanted to open your website `https://preppylion.com` and my browser (Chrome on Win10) throws a warning (actually, a "Privacy Error") `Your connection is not private`, just FYI.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Thanks. I created the domain a couple decades ago and never got around to installing an SSL certificate on it. I just fixed that... it should no longer say that in 24 hours or so.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the follow-up. Are you still actively working on the book?

Comment: Yes, I was working on an appendix just today. I'm aiming to get it done by the end of summer, circumstances permitting.

Comment: Looking forward, have a nice evening.